# How to load more elements with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

for a while I am trying to find how to make a load more(elements from an array) button,using Angular.

I have 9 elements in array, I use `ng-repeat` to loop them, and `limitTo:3` to output first 3.

Questions:

1: is possible to make a load more button using only angular?(load more button is at bottom in example)

2: if not, how to make this work using jQuery?

http://plnkr.co/edit/1gHB9zr0lbEBwlCYJ3jQ

Thanks!

Comment: What should the button do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to think of jQuery, as you could solve this problem easily by using AngularJS itself.

You could maintain a variable inside your controller, name it as `limit`, then increment the `limit` variable inside `loadMore()` function.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in travel.cruise | limitTo:travel.limit" class="cruises">

  ....COntent here...

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('TravelController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cruise = cruises;
    vm.limit = 3;

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
      var increamented = vm.limit + 3;
      vm.limit = incremented > vm.cruise.length ? vm.cruise.length : increamented;
    };
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TixfXRngVyfHK6SOwYR7?p=preview)

Comment: Don't mind, some times `vm.limit`  size can be greater than *content size* in your logic. `var increamented = vm.limit + 3;
      vm.limit = increamented > vm.cruise.length ? increamented : vm.limit + 3;`

Comment: @shaishabroy Good catch..thats my bad..wrote exactly opposite condition..I've corrected it..

Answer (score 1):

You can combine @Pankaj Parkar response with [infiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) so you dont need even the button.

Answer (score 1):

No need of cracking any deep coding. Its simple to add just **one line of code**

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in travel.cruise | limitTo:travel.limit" class="cruises">

..NG Repeat..

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
      vm.limit = vm.limit + 3;
};
```

Assigning variable to increase by the 3 or more number will make your code work easily.

Simple and easy trick