# Show more/less link for dynamic list items in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I created 'show more' link for dynamic list items which have more than three items but I have a problem with change this link to 'show less' after click 'show more'. I need two another icon for that. Any ideas how I can change it? It is possible to create it only with ng directives in HTML without functions in a controller?

My code:

```
<ul ng-if="::document.actUnitMonographViewList" class="commentary-snippets">
  <li ng-repeat="monograph in document.actUnitMonographViewList | limitTo:showMore ? document.actUnitMonographViewList.length : 3">
     <i ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1"
        class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      <a href="" ng-href="{{ ::getPublicationLink(monograph, 'monograph') }}"
         ng-class="{'arrow-link': document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1}" 
         user-preferences-target>{{::monograph.title}}
      </a>
   </li>
   <li ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      <a ng-click="showMore = true">Show more</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      <a ng-click="">Show less</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which angular version do you use?

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211888/how-to-load-more-elements-with-angular

Comment: This appears to be a data hiding problem. New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. See [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). The solution is to use a dot, i.e. `ng-click="document.showMore = true"`.

Comment: There is also potential for problems when using [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document) in an AngularJS expression. `document` is a global variable and may cause problems when using it as a scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code like below and it works! :)

```
<ul ng-if="::document.actUnitMonographViewList" class="commentary-snippets">
  <li ng-repeat="monograph in document.actUnitMonographViewList | limitTo: monograph.limit ? document.actUnitMonographViewList.length : 3">
  <i ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    <a href="" ng-href="{{ ::getPublicationLink(monograph, 'monograph') }}" ng-class="{'arrow-link': document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1}" user-preferences-target>
      {{::monograph.title}}
    </a>
  </li>
  <li ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
    <i class="list-items-toggle-arrow" ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-up': monograph.limit, 'fa fa-chevron-down': !monograph.limit}" ng-click="monograph.limit = !monograph.limit"></i>
    <a ng-click="monograph.limit = !monograph.limit" class="list-items-toggle-link">{{monograph.limit ? 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.LESS' : 'LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.MORE' | translate}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ngIf, see following:

```
<ul ng-if="::document.actUnitMonographViewList" class="commentary-snippets">
  <li ng-repeat="monograph in document.actUnitMonographViewList | limitTo:showMore ? document.actUnitMonographViewList.length : 3">
     <i ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      <a href="" ng-href="{{ ::getPublicationLink(monograph, 'monograph') }}" ng-class="{'arrow-link': document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 1}" user-preferences-target>{{::monograph.title}}</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > document.itemsLimit">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      <a ng-if="showMore==false" ng-click="showMore = true" class="">Show more</a>
      <a ng-if="showMore==true" ng-click="showMore = false" class="">Show less</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made sth like that and it doesn't work... I need another icon which I want to use for 'show less' link so it must be in separate <li></li>  tag                                
<li ng-if="showMore === false" ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <a ng-click="showMore = true" translate="LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.MORE"></a>
  </li>
  <li ng-if="showMore === true" ng-show="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > 3">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
  <a ng-click="showMore = false" translate="LIST_ITEMS_CONTENT.LESS"></a>
  </li>

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use `ng-if` statement based on your `document.actUnitMonographViewList` length. Try with something like this:

```
<a ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length > showMore" ng-click="showMore = true" class="">Show more</a>
```

and then add showLess

```
<a ng-if="document.actUnitMonographViewList.length <= showMore" ng-click="showLess= true" class="">Show less</a>
```

Here is example of something like that: 
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/nuyxRk9ioXDGjq2n?preview

Comment: ng-click="showLess= true" ? It doesn't work. I don't see a "showLess" value in any part of the code in the example from the link above.

Comment: Yeah, that is right, but you can create showLess function

Comment: @Natalia Gurgul check out my plunker, and try create similar function showMore and showLess

Comment: In my opinion this is the easiest way to showing less/more in ng-repeat